# according to choice specific line should run in cmd.exe using batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I wanted to give this choice

```
@echo off
echo what operation you wanted to perform
echo a:creating a new web server?
echo or
echo b:Edit root url for already existed web server
set /P var = "What is your option a or b"

if "%var%" == "A" (
    cd C:\Program Files\Infor\Mongoose\Tools
    infordbcl.exe addwebserver -name:sample -product:Mongoose -rooturl:https://uscovwmongoose3
)
if "%var%" == "B" (
    infordbcl.exe addwebserver -name:sample -product:Mongoose -rooturl:https://mongoose.com - 
    mode:edit
 )
```

I ran this batch file using powershell. 
After entering the choice A or B, the commands specified in if blocks are not getting executed in cmd.exe
Is their any syntax errors in it, please let me know

Comment: a couple of things - If tests on strings are case sensitive - User would have to type in A or B in Capital form. Secondly, filepaths containing spaces should be doublequoted. `"cd C:\Program Files\Infor\Mongoose\Tools"`

Also, CHOICE is the better command for menu selection in batch

Comment: to render them case Insensitive, use `IF /I "%var%"` == "A" (`

Comment: Even after keeping double quotes to the path(cd "C:|Program Files\Files\Infor\MongoosTools"), their is not change. command in if block are not getting executed. Is there any other way to do this? Firstly I tried using choice, same is repeated.

Comment: there is another issue within your code, in how you define the variable `var`. the space between the variable name and the `=` gets included in the variable name - So `var` is never defined, `varSPACE` is.

The mode:edit in the second condition forms a part of the parameter for the previous line, and should be on the same line - I'll presume you've made an error in formatting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Choice could be used here:

```
@echo off

Choice /N /C ce /M "  <?> (C)reate new Server   <?> (E)dit root url for existing web server"
If Errorlevel 2 (
    REM If the  Change directory command is also meant to execute in this block, remove and place CD command prior to choice command.
    infordbcl.exe addwebserver -name:sample -product:Mongoose -rooturl:https://mongoose.com -mode:edit
    ) Else (
    REM confirm if lack of url extension is correct
    cd "C:\Program Files\Infor\Mongoose\Tools"
    infordbcl.exe addwebserver -name:sample -product:Mongoose -rooturl:https://uscovwmongoose3
)
```

Explanation:

`/N` hides the default prompt (whatever keys are defined using /C or the default Y/N if /C is not used)

`/C` allows definition of keys within the range 0-9 and A-Z

- errorlevel for each key is set according to occurance after the /C
  switch
- for `/C ce`, `c` will return Errorlevel 1, `e` will return errorlevel 2
  and so on

`/M "string"` allows a custom string to be defined to explain the Choice. Encase the string within doublequotes.

**When you test the returned Errorlevel**

You must test from Highest to Lowest.

This is because the command intepreter reads `If Errorlevel n` as `If Errorlevel n or higher`

For more information and usage examples, type `choice /?` in cmd.exe